# Why doesn't "print (string)" prints the string when the condition is "if '-' in string:"

Tags: python-3.x

I am pretty much new with Python and have browsed the Answers on stackoverflow but yet to solve this question.

I am trying to execute a simple program in Python to print **`-26.507`** from a text as follows :

```
my_string = "                                         latitude        longitude       N         error (95% confidence interval) Station Name                            ddd mm ss.sssss ddd mm ss.sssss  meters    meters USER LOCATION                            28  0  0.00000  95  0  0.00000  -26.507    0.096"
my_string.split()
print(my_string)
for string in my_string:
    if '-' in string:
        print (string)
```

Here, `print(my_string)` does prints the entire string. 
But the second print statement prints only **`-`** instead of **`-26.507`**

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: string becomes one character if you do `for string in my string` what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you can describe what exactly you need, there are much better methods than that.

Comment: I simply need to print `-26.507`

Comment: Yeah, but depending on how you data looks like you could just  split everything and query the field if your data is always the same, than you don't even have to query `if` but just do elements[12]

Comment: Well, I have ensured that `Selenium` will return me a string only, pure `String`

Comment: Ok in that case this might always be the same, i've edited my Answer, you can just query it in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do in python is

```
line = "                                         latitude        longitude       N         error (95% confidence interval) Station Name                            ddd mm ss.sssss ddd mm ss.sssss  meters    meters USER LOCATION                            28  0  0.00000  95  0  0.00000  -26.507    0.096"
elements = line.split()
for i in elements:
    if '-' in i:
        print(i)
```

If you know where the element always is going to be, you can have this in one line as well. As we converted your text into a list of texts, we can query it as follows:

```
line.split()[-2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but significance of `[-2]`

Comment: tells `give me the second item from the back`

Comment: Thanks a ton for `line.split()[-2]`

Answer (score 4):

When you `.split()` the string, without assigning this to a variable, it actually **does not "split" the string into a list. It does not modify the string `my_string`.** hence when you do `for string in my_string`, you will end up with single characters.

Do the following, and you will see the result:

```
my_string = "                                         latitude        longitude       N         error (95% confidence interval) Station Name                            ddd mm ss.sssss ddd mm ss.sssss  meters    meters USER LOCATION                            28  0  0.00000  95  0  0.00000  -26.507    0.096"
my_string.split()
for i, v in enumerate(my_string):
    print(i, v)
```

where `i` is the index, and `v` the value.

do the following, which is assigning the "split string" to a variable, which becomes a list, you will see a different output.

```
my_string = "                                         latitude        longitude       N         error (95% confidence interval) Station Name                            ddd mm ss.sssss ddd mm ss.sssss  meters    meters USER LOCATION                            28  0  0.00000  95  0  0.00000  -26.507    0.096"
my_list = my_string.split()
for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i, v)
```

Which is probably more like what you want.

From here you experiment further splitting/enumerating.

Comment: Thanks, your solution does gets me all the items in `enumerated` form but my question was to print only `-26.507` which would be passed to other function. So I think creating `enumeration` will be overhead as a solution.

Comment: @DebanjanB my code is not meant to be your final code. My code explains what was happening, more educational than copy/paste, here is your answer.  I hope my code samples explains exactly that. My answer is for the question "Can someone help me out please?". In your final code I wouldn't use enumerate.

Comment: Yes Sir, It was pretty helpful and useful to me. My Upvote must speak volumes.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
my_string = "                                         latitude        longitude       N         error (95% confidence interval) Station Name                            ddd mm ss.sssss ddd mm ss.sssss  meters    meters USER LOCATION                            28  0  0.00000  95  0  0.00000  -26.507    0.096"
strings = my_string.split()
print(my_string)
for string in strings:
    if '-' == string[0]:
        print (string)
```

The primary mistake that you made is this: `my_string.split()` doesn't actually change `my_string`, instead, it returns a list of sections of `my_string`, split at the spaces. Thus, when you did `for string in my_string`, you were iterating over each character in the string `my_string`, when you *thought* that you were iterating over each word. By assigning a new variable to be the list of words, you can iterate over the words.

Comment: Thanks. It works. A followup question, when you say `a list of sections of my_string, split at the spaces` it is a `List` now. Then why in `for string in my_string` I was iterating over each character?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
my_string = "                                         latitude        longitude       N         error (95% confidence interval) Station Name                            ddd mm ss.sssss ddd mm ss.sssss  meters    meters USER LOCATION                            28  0  0.00000  95  0  0.00000  -26.507    0.096"
new_string = my_string.split()
print(new_string)
for string in new_string:
    if '-' in string:
        print (string)
```

I think you will get the point. You are splitting my_string but my_string doesn't contain the spitted array.

Comment: Thanks. You nailed my wrong conception. So `my_string.split()` will not not split itself. Am I right?

Comment: It will split but not reference the spitted array. If you do my_string = my_string.split(), then it will do what you want. It will  split and also reference the new spitted array.

Comment: Thanks again. You explanation is perfect.